# Is Google Translate image feature accurate at this? (Characters identified: 金陵子弟來相送，欲行不行各盡觴)

Tags: translation, character-identification

[image: enter image hihere]

I couldn't find a good translation for this since Google Translate with picture feature probably is not as good for such a long sentence

So I came here: Google Translate says "Jingling children come and go in the wish" is google translate accurate at this?

I was unable to identify even the first character; see [my attempt here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssulj.png).

Comment: right column: 金陵（pre-Han name for Nanjing
common place name）子弟来相送（see sb. off ）left column:欲行不行各尽觞

 

jukuu：1.  "With my comrades of the city who are here to see me off; And as each of them drains his cup, I say to him in parting,"
 金陵子弟来相送, 欲行不行各尽觞。

Comment: sorry i couldnt quite get "i say to him in parting" ... how does this work in english meaning?

Comment: other users neither, maybe it should be "them" ("say" may have surfaced in translation, not containing context) 
once the text is entered into any browser, the latter will return the source: 出自唐朝诗人李白的古诗作品《金陵酒肆留别》 see e.g. https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=%E9%87%91%E9%99%B5%E5%AD%90%E5%BC%9F%E6%9D%A5%E7%9B%B8%E9%80%81%2C+%E6%AC%B2%E8%A1%8C%E4%B8%8D%E8%A1%8C%E5%90%84%E5%B0%BD%E8%A7%9E&ei=UTF-8&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002

Answer (score 4):

These two verses came from 李白 (Li Bai)'s poem

https://fanti.dugushici.com/mingju/9526

> "金陵子弟來相送，欲行不行各盡觴。" 出自於李白的《金陵酒肆留别》
>
> 朝代：唐代
>
> 作者：李白
>
> 原文：
>
> 風吹柳花滿店香，吳姬壓酒喚客嘗。
>
> **金陵子弟來相送，欲行不行各盡觴**。
>
> 請君試問東流水，別意與之誰短長。

~

> 註釋
>
> 1.金陵：我國今江蘇省南京市。
>
> Jinling: Today's  Nanjing City , Jiangsu Province, China

~

> 3.子弟：指李白的朋友。
>
> 子弟(sons): Refers to 'native sons of Jinling' -- Li Bai's friends

~

> 4.欲行：要走的人，指李白自己。不行：送行的人，指金陵子弟。
>
> '欲行' (about to leave) refers to 'the person who was about to leave'. And that person was Li Bai himself.
>
> '不行' (not leaving) refers to 'the people who were not leaving'. And they  were Li Bai's friends.

~

> 5.盡觴(shāng)：喝盡杯中的酒。也指乾杯。
>
> 盡(finish)
>
> 盡觴: drink down the whole cup of wine. Also refers to the cheers

~

> "金陵子弟來相送，欲行不行各盡觴"
>
> " The native sons of Jinling (my friends) came to see me off; I, the one who is about to leave, and my friends who are not leaving, all drunk down a cups of wine (before we part). "

Comment: Ohhh okey... thats very interesting it took me long time to decipher it even tho you were explaining it to me... now the mistery is why is this into a dizi flute... very strange world, thank you so much Tang Ho